# Force display of soft keyboard in Windows Phone 8

Tags: user-interface, windows-phone-8

Windows Phone 8 Login Screen and also Wallet provides a 'Logon Screen' where you could enter the PIN.
(e.g. http://666kb.com/i/cnptoaia87hn7aaib.jpg)

I want to achieve the same in my app but I having a hard time to force the soft keyboard to be displayed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use InputScope to achive in wp:

```
<TextBox Name="txtPhoneNumber" Height="100">
                <TextBox.InputScope>
                    <InputScope>
                        <InputScopeName NameValue="Number" />
                    </InputScope>
                </TextBox.InputScope>
            </TextBox>
```

Comment: Yes but the back button or touching outside the TextBox still hides the Keyboard. I could also not prevent that be overriding the handle Hardware button event

Comment: if you are doing in wp then this is by default and you could not change it by overriding

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the keyboard to pop up when page is loaded.

here is how to do it

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textbox.Focus();
        // next line is to highlight all the text in the textbox  

        textbox.InnerTextBox.Select(url.InnerTextBox.Text.Length, 0);

    }
```